# Inserting JSON data into mysql using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have json input as mentioned below am decoding the the json response and inserting it into the mysql database,Now am converting this into Codeigniter I am not able to understand how to write the controller and the model for the below code,Please let me know how to write the controller and model, also am providing the controller and model which is written by me

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
// read json file
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$timestamp = time();
$date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
$createdon = $date_time;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    // $filename = 'employee.json';
    // $json_data = file_get_contents($filename);
    $json_data = $_POST['QUESTION'];
    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($json_data, true);
    // print_r($data);
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
        $jsonData = $data['DATA'];
        $jsonAnswers = $data['ANSWERS'];
        $drcode = $data['DATA']['DRCODE'];
        $divcode = $data['DATA']['DIVCODE'];
        $brdcode = $data['DATA']['BRDCODE'];
        $prdcode = $data['DATA']['PRDCODE'];
        // echo $drmobile." -- ";
        for ($i = 0;$i < sizeof($data['ANSWERS']);$i++) {
            $quecode[$i] = $data['ANSWERS'][$i]['ADCODE'];
            $answer[$i] = $data['ANSWERS'][$i]['ANSWER'];
            $quecodes = $quecode[$i];
            $answers = $answer[$i];
            // echo $quecode[$i]." <--> ".$answer[$i]."<br/>";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ANSWERS(DRCODE,ADCODE,DIVCODE,BRDCODE,PRDCODE,ANSWERS,CREATEDON)VALUES ('$drcode', '$quecode[$i]', '$divcode', '$brdcode', '$prdcode', '$answer[$i]', '$createdon')";
            $qur = mysql_query($sql);
            if ($qur) {
                $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Data added Successfully!");
            } else {
                $json = array("status" => 2, "msg" => "Already Submitted");
            }
        }
        // echo "<br/>-----------<br/>";

    }
} else {
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
}
@mysql_close($conn);
/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
//close connection

?>
```

**Json Input**

```
{
    "DATA": {
        "DRCODE": "D40504",
        "DIVCODE": 1,
        "BRDCODE": 5,
        "PRDCODE": 5
    },
    "ANSWERS": [{
        "ADCODE": 1,
        "ANSWER": "VERY GOOD"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 2,
        "ANSWER": "GOOD"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 3,
        "ANSWER": "SGH"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 4,
        "ANSWER": "NO"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 5,
        "ANSWER": "NO"
    }, {
        "ADCODE": 6,
        "ANSWER": "CGHJ"
    }]
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function feedback_post() {
    $json_data = $this->post('QUESTION');
    $data = $this->json_decode($json_data, true);
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {
        $jsonData = $this->$data['DATA'];
        $jsonAnswers = $this->$data['ANSWERS'];
        $drcode = $this->$data['DATA']['DRCODE'];
        $divcode = $this->$data['DATA']['DIVCODE'];
        $brdcode = $this->$data['DATA']['BRDCODE'];
        $prdcode = $this->$data['DATA']['PRDCODE'];
        for ($i = 0;$i < sizeof($data['ANSWERS']);$i++) {
            $quecode[$i] = $this->$data['ANSWERS'][$i]['ADCODE'];
            $answer[$i] = $this->$data['ANSWERS'][$i]['ANSWER'];
            $quecodes = $this->$quecode[$i];
            $answers = $this->$answer[$i];
        }
        $insert_array = array('DRCODE' => $drcode, 'DIVCODE' => $divcode, 'BRDCODE' => $speciality, 'PRDCODE' => $prdcode, 'ANSWER' => $answers, 'ADCODE' => $quecodes);
        $feedback_data = $this->Rest_user_model->feedbacksubmission($insert_array);
        if ($feedback_data) {
            $message = ['status' => 1,
            // 'result' => array(),
            'message' => 'Feedback Submitted Successfully'];
        } else {
            $message = ['status' => 2,
            // 'result' => array(),
            'message' => 'Feedback Submitted Successfully'];
        }
        $this->set_response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public function feedback_post()
{
    $objDate = new DateTime();

    $data = json_decode($this->input->post('QUESTION'), true);
    if (is_array($data)) 
    {
        foreach($data['ANSWERS'] AS $arrAnswer)
        {
            $arrInsertData =
            [
                'DRCODE' => $data['DATA']['DRCODE'],
                'DIVCODE' => $data['DATA']['DIVCODE'],
                'BRDCODE' => $data['DATA']['BRDCODE'],
                'PRDCODE' => $data['DATA']['PRDCODE'],
                'ADCODE' => $arrAnswer['ADCODE'],
                'ANSWERS' => $arrAnswer['ANSWER'],
                'CREATEDON' => $objDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ];

            $feedback_data = $this->Rest_user_model->feedbacksubmission($arrInsertData);
            $message = ($feedback_data) ?   ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Feedback Submitted Successfully'] :   ['status' => 2, 'message' => 'Already Submitted'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $message = ["status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted"];
    }
    $this->set_response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

this is pretty much basic understanding of php - but you've to ask yourself - if you've multiple answers - what happens if one fails and one is successful ?

Because your sample php code is simply wrong...